# Clip to maximum / minimum finite int/float/double?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I'd like to clip some Tensorflow variables with tf.clip_by_value to the most positive / negative **finite** value possible.
I'd like to reach a similar behavior like numpy.nan_to_num()

How do I get these values, given some data type?
Does this clipping affect the optimizer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All [TensorFlow datatypes have the min and max properties](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/DType#max), that return the maximum and minimum values the type can hold. E.g.,

```
import tensorflow as tf

print( tf.float32.max )
```

Outputs:

> 3.4028235e+38